# WooCommerce - Remove Featured Product Image From Product Page Gallery

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am looking to remove the main product image (that appears on the main shop page) from the product gallery shown on single product pages. The main product image is shown as the first image in the gallery on single product pages. All of the shop products are simple, downloadable products.

I have tried using the following function but it removes both the main product image from the product page, as well as removing the product image gallery completely.

```
add_filter('woocommerce_single_product_image_thumbnail_html', 'remove_featured_image', 10, 2);
function remove_featured_image($html, $attachment_id ) {
    global $post, $product;

    $featured_image = get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID );

    if ( $attachment_id == $featured_image )
        $html = '';

    return $html;
}
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: You dont get the gallery bcs you need to include it in this hook again.

Comment: You need to do the following. Copy product-image.php template in your theme - https://woocommerce.com/document/template-structure/ . After that comment the if ( $post_thumbnail_id ) { } else { } statement and you are done.

Comment: Thank you. So comment out the whole if else statement but keep verything from `echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_single_product_image_thumbnail_html', $html, $post_thumbnail_id ); `?

Comment: sorry yes comment on that too you won't need it. Unless you want to show the default featured image if none is set then comment or just return empty $html in the if statement

Comment: I gave that a try (both with and without `echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_single_product_image_thumbnail_html', $html, $post_thumbnail_id );` but it didn't work, the main product image is still showing as the first image in the gallery (both thumbnail and main image).

Comment: That could be theme related issue if its overwriting the hook too. I have tested on storefront and its working fine. If you can change to storefront and test too to confirm its working. If its all alright then you know its the theme.

Comment: The issue was theme related. The solution you described above worked perfectly.